# Identity with integer partitions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, integer-partitions

I have to prove that $p(n)=p(n-1)+\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}p_{k}(n-k)$ and I am quite stuck on it...
My first intuition was that, as $p(n)-p(n-1)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ that don't have $1$ in them, proving the identity was the same as proving that the number of partitions of $n$ without $1$ is $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}p_{k}(n-k)$. Nevertheless, I wasn't able to continue. I also thought about how, using the known recurrence formulas with partitions, could I simplify it; as $p_{k}(n)=p_{k-1}(n-1)+p_{k}(n-k)$, I could write $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}p_{k}(n-k)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}p_{k}(n)-\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}p_{k-1}(n-1)$. I also know that $p(n)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} p_{k}(n)$ and $p(n-1)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} p_{k}(n-1)$... I suppose that, with all this, I could arrive somewhere... But, I haven't been able to do it.
A hint, or some help, would help a lot! Thanks in advanced!

**Note**: $p(n)$ denotes the number of partitions of $n$, and $p_{k}(n)$ denotes the number of partitions of $n$ with exactly $k$ summands.

Comment: What is $p_k\vphantom{dummy}$?

Comment: @nejimban, $p_{k}(n)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ with exactly $k$ summands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that $p(n)-p(n-1)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ with no part equal to $1$. We just need to prove that the number of partitions of $n$ with no part equal to $1$ is also $\sum_{k=1}^{n/2}p_k(n-k)$.

The idea is to find a bijection between these two sets:
$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
\text{partitions of $n$ with $k$ parts}\\
\text{with no part equal to $1$.}\end{matrix}\right\}
\longleftrightarrow
\left\{\begin{matrix}
\text{partitions of $n-k$}\\
\text{with exactly $k$ parts.}\end{matrix}\right\}
$$
Once you have this, you are done by summing over $k$.

Can you think of a bijection between these two sets? Further hint behind a spoiler in case you need it:

> What kind of natural operation can you do to a partition of $n$ with $k$ parts in order to turn it into a partition of $n-k$?

Comment: First, thanks a lot! I think I have the bijection... I have based my argument on a Ferrers diagram. If I represent a partition of $n$ with $k$ parts with no part equal to $1$, deleting the first column, I would still have a partition in $k$ parts (as no $1$ exists in the first partition), but, in this case of $n-k$ (we have deleted $k$ symbols of the diagram). Reversely, we can just have any partition of $n-k$ in k parts and add $k$ as a column, which will make all the possible $1$ in the partition dissapear, and we would obtained a partition of $n$ with $k$ parts (without $1$). Is this ok?

Comment: @rubikman23 Exactly!